# when -a%b for a,b= integers then remainder is 0 but if a,b are double then result is -0

Tags: java, integer, double

```
class TestSampl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = -47, b = 47;
        double c = -333.0, d = 333.0;                                        
        //why does integer print output as 
        System.out.println("Integer " + a/b + " " + a%b );  
        // and double print output as -0
        System.out.println("Double " + c/d + " " + c%d );   
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it print out?

Comment: Hope people who are down voting this know the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you confused about the integer modulus or the double modulus?

There is no `-0` integer, so there's very little option than to have `0` as the result. However doubles have positive and negative zeros (not to mention things like positive infinity, negative infinity and `NaN`), so for doubles the answer would be "because that's how it's defined".

Comment: Only God and Gosling's know the reason for this behaviour :-/

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I may be wrong but I don't recall James Gosling being involved in IEEE 754.

Comment: Hey there kayaman there is more than that what have you said in case of integer the value are stored in the form of 2's complement that is why integer variable can't print -0

Comment: @NikhilBalyan Well that's the underlying technical reason for why we don't have negative and positive zero for integers.

Comment: @Kayaman  yeah!! everyone wants the "technical explanation".